# How to detect shake Gesture in your iPhone Cocos2D? in iOS 8

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, uiaccelerometer

My cocos2d app have shake feature, I develop shake feature using UIAccelerometer. In iOS 8 UIAccelerometer meter is not working. Can any one help me, How to detect shake Gesture in cocos2d app.

Thanks....

Comment: `- (void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer*)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration*)acceleration`
is this function not working .. even if you use .. 
`[[UIAccelerometer sharedAccelerometer] setDelegate:self];` .. or `self.isAccelerometerEnabled = YES;` in `init` or `onEnter` in `CCLayer`?

Comment: let me know if down answer is not what you are looking for. will be happy to change or delete. –

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your View Controller:

```
override func motionEnded(motion: UIEventSubtype, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if motion == .MotionShake {
        // do something cool
    }
}
```